# How to make window transparent when using Frames and Pages?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have a simple application I'm trying to make.

The idea is to start with a login screen and then move to an admin screen. For this, after looking for answers I stumbled upon Frames and Pages. The problem that I'm having now is that it seems that Pages are not compatible with translucency?

This is what I get when using Frame and Page:

[image: Login with Frame and Page]

This is what I want to replicate:

[image: Login with just Window]

This is the main window with pages:

```
<Window 
    x:Class="Membership2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Membership2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1366"
    AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
    </Grid>
    
</Window>
```

As you can see, Background property is set to Transparent, but it does nothing. I also tried setting the Grid Background and Frame Background to Transparent without success.

Also, WindowStartupLocation is set to CenterScreen when using Pages, but it also does nothing it seems.

EDIT:

So this problem arises when StartupUri (in App.xaml) is set to my LoginPage.xaml instead of the MainWindow.xaml (described previously).

This is my LoginPage.xaml:

```
<Page x:Class="Membership2.LoginPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Membership2"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="550" d:DesignWidth="450"
      MaxHeight="550" MaxWidth="450"
      Title="LoginPage"
      RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"
      FontFamily="./Resources/Fonts/#Dosis"
      xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
      xmlns:fw="clr-namespace:SourceChord.FluentWPF;assembly=FluentWPF"
      ShowsNavigationUI="False"
      Background="Transparent"
      >

    <Grid
        fw:PointerTracker.Enabled="True" Background="Transparent">

        <Border
            Background="WhiteSmoke"
            CornerRadius="7"
            Margin="30, 75, 30, 0">
        </Border>

        <Ellipse
            Width="50"
            Height="50"
            Fill="WhiteSmoke"
            Margin="0,-450,0,0">
        </Ellipse>

        <materialDesign:PackIcon
            Kind="AccountCircle"
            Width="150"
            Height="150"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            FontSize="50"
            Foreground="#7ea4b3"
            Grid.Column="1">
        </materialDesign:PackIcon>

        <Label
            Content="Administración"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Margin="0,140,0,0"
            FontSize="30"
            FontFamily="./Resources/Fonts/#Dosis">

        </Label>

        <TextBox
            x:Name="Username"
            Width="230"
            Height="45"
            FontSize="25"
            TextWrapping="NoWrap"
            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTextBox}"
            FontWeight="Light"
            RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"
            FontFamily="./Resources/Fonts/#Dosis"
            Margin="0, 0, 0, 50"
            materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Usuario">
        </TextBox>

        <PasswordBox
            x:Name="Password"
            Width="230"
            Height="45"
            FontSize="25"
            FontWeight="Light"
            RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"
            Margin="0, 150, 0, 0"
            BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
            materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Contraseña"
            materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.DecorationVisibility="Visible">
        </PasswordBox>

        <Button
            x:Name="Login"
            Width="150"
            Height="48"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Margin="0,0,0,70"
            FontSize="25"
            FontWeight="Light"
            Background="LightGray"
            Style="{StaticResource ButtonRevealStyle}"
            BorderThickness="2,2,2,2">
            Ingresar
        </Button>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: i Really dint Under when you said it not working. i tested it now

Comment: AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Frame Height="50" Width="50"  Background="Transparent" x:Name="MainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Frame Height="50" Width="50"  Background="Red" x:Name="MainFrame1" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="1"/>

Comment: its working as expected

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. The translucency problem arises when, in App.xaml the property StartupUri is set to my LoginPage.xaml. If I leave it as MainWindow.xaml, then the window shows translucency correctly. Will update the original post to reflect this.